# Android Outlined Material Component not showing label properly

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have the following edit box (from material library)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/myTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:counterMaxLength="20"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="My Title"

        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I expected the hint text ("My title"), to appear on the boundary of the edit box, instead it is coming inside of the text box, and the outline of text box doesnt have any text.

How do i fix this?

EDIT - my apps theme's parent is "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Have you tried putting the hint on the `TextInputLayout`, rather than the `TextInputEditText`?

Comment: yes. still same.

Comment: actually, the hint starts inside the box, but when I start typing, the text goes on top of the boundary, which is how I believe this is supposed to work.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the hint is in the field when empty and is a floating label otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Incase there are others who got confused, the hint text is shown inside the box when empty , and becomes floating with text. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the label to be shown on the outline boundary box by default by adding *app:expandedHintEnabled="false"* to the **TextInputLayout**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
    android:hint="Label"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: result]